# Implement asynchrony in java for an endpoint that is blocking while being consulted recurrently by another function

Tags: java, asynchronous, feign

I have this fragment of code that has to be executed repeatedly to validate deployment status

```
while (true) {
    var logsFlags = devOpsClient.obtainInfoTaskFromRelease(personalToken,  responseCreateRelease.getEnvironments().get(0).getReleaseId(), responseCreateRelease.getEnvironments().get(0).getId());
    if ("inProgress".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus()) || "queued".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Thread.currentThread().
        log.info("Count {}", count++);
        continue;
    } else if ("succeeded".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
        break;
    } else if ("rejected".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
        throw new Exception("The resource to be displayed failed, check de Logs");
    }
    break;
}
log.info("Status Finished - Resource {} deployed", data.getResource());
```

This makes use of the feign client

```
@FeignClient(
        value = "devopsCell-svc",
        url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com"
)
public interface DevOpsClient {

    @PostMapping("/cell/Deployments-Terraform/_apis/release/releases?api-version=7.1-preview.8")
    ResponseCreateRelease executeManualRelease(
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
            @RequestBody ReleaseDTO releaseDTO
            );

    @GetMapping("/cell/Deployments-Terraform/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=7.1-preview.7")
    DeploymentDTO obtainInfoTaskFromRelease(
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
            @PathVariable("releaseId") Integer releaseId,
            @PathVariable("environmentId") Integer environmentId
    );
```

The point is that it is blocking since as I repeatedly consult the status, obtainInfoTaskFromRelease becomes blocked so I would not know how to implement the asynchronous calls and at least that function is no longer blocking, since from the controller it has its own endpoint and is not can run by the above

```
@PostMapping("/data-deploy")
    public ResponseEntity<String> dataIaCDevOpS(@RequestBody RequestIaCDTO requestList) throws Exception {
        return databaseService.dataIaC(Shield.blindRequestIaCDTO(requestList));
    }

@PostMapping("/obtain-tasks-release")
    public SimplifiedDeploymentDTO responseTaskRelease(@RequestParam(name = "releaseId") Integer releaseId,
                                                       @RequestParam(name = "environmentId") Integer environmentId){
        return databaseService.responseTaskRelease(Integer.valueOf(Shield.blindStr(String.valueOf(releaseId))), Integer.valueOf(Shield.blindStr(String.valueOf(environmentId))));
    }
```

obtain-tasks-release is an endpoint that consumes obtainInfoTaskFromRelease to show the status, so the current problem is that if the while is repeatedly consulting obtainInfoTaskFromRelease, if I call obtain-tasks-release it will not respond to me until the while does so stop consulting

I appreciate if you can guide me to be able to carry out the process of including some asynchronous solution that does not block the obtainInfoTaskFromRelease function.

Comment: Firstly, there's something missing in your first snippet. What is the line `Thread.currentThread().` meant to be?

Comment: Secondly what is blocked where? The `/obtain-tasks-release` endpoint doesn't appear to call the `DevOpsClient` at all, and your loop sleeps for 3 seconds and doesn't appear to hold any locks while it's sleeping. You need to explain exactly what `/obtain-tasks-release` is waiting for.

Comment: @tgdavies Ignore that line, it was just something I was testing and regarding the other thing, as the controller calls a function that uses the same feign interface, that means that the controller has the ability to call the feign and also the while can call the feign, both call the same "function" called "obtainInfoTaskFromRelease", so if the while is running for 5 minutes, trying to call it from the controller is not going to work. serve because the thread is busy, sleep is just so that the while is executed every 3 seconds and have greater control over the response

Comment: Please edit your question instead of including corrections and clarifications in comments. But you have still not explained what is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want know when is in progress, failed or complete you cannot make this in a single request.

Because the first call can be response with pending but if you want continuiosly the current state, you must call N time the endpoint obtain-tasks-release (polling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)). This method for a personal opinion i don't like.

Another way is make a streaming communication using for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-grpc-streaming

This example is to use the polling communication.

```java
private CompletableFuture<String> methodToCallAnotherService() {

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> devOpsClient.obtainInfoTaskFromRelease(personalToken,
                    responseCreateRelease.getEnvironments().get(0).getReleaseId(), responseCreateRelease.getEnvironments().get(0).getId()))
            .thenApply(logsFlags -> {
                if ("inProgress".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus()) || "queued".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
                    log.info("Count {}", count++);
                    return logsFlags.getStatus();
                } else if ("succeeded".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
                    return logsFlags.getStatus();
                } else if ("rejected".equalsIgnoreCase(logsFlags.getStatus())) {
                    return "The resource to be displayed failed, check de Logs";
                } else {
                    return "unknown state";
                }
            });
}
```

Your endpoint will return a CompletableFuture that will maintain the current state.